# SQL Query to find a record with a certain number of specific characters (4 vertical bars)

Tags: sql

In the database I'm working with, we have a certain naming convention that should be followed and I'm trying to fix errors.

For example, one of the correctly named records would be:
Blue Insurance | Blue Agency | Blue Agency | BL26 | Blue Insurance

Is there any way to search for all records that do not have 4 vertical bars in them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from tablename
where length(colname) - length(replace(colname,'|','')) <> 4
```

Change `length` according to the database being used.